# Using Devise's current_user in Test Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

In some of my controllers I need to use the group(s) that belong to my logged in user(`current_user.groups`). When I try to test; I don't seem to have this `current_user` though:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

So I figured I should create that current_user with Devise.

I've read the documentation of Devise stating I should add the following to my **test_helper.rb**:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
    def setup
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
        sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end
end
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick though; Whenever I run `rake test` I get the following errors:

```
  1) Error:
ActivitiesControllerTest#test_should_create_activity:
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionController::TestCase::FactoryGirl
    test/test_helper.rb:22:in `setup'
```

Comment: Do you have the factory_girl_rails gem included in the test group in your Gemfile?

Comment: I was assuming it came with the Devise gem. Since the whole login/signup thing works like a charm in my application.

Comment: Than why don't I need it to login normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the factory_girl_rails gem in your Gemfile. I usually include it in both the development and test group, but just the test environment is fine for your example.

```
group :development, :test do
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

And then run `bundle install`.

factory_girl_rails is used when you are creating the user fixture in your test:

`sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)`

Then you need to create a factory (which is almost like a fixture):

`rails generate factory_girl:model user`

This will create the file: `test/factories/users.rb`

Read more about factory_girl_rails and how to define factories here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails

Comment: It throws me this: `PictogramsControllerTest#test_should_update_pictogram:
ArgumentError: Factory not registered: user
    test/test_helper.rb:21:in `setup'`